# Unreal Engine Vehicle Physics issue

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I am trying to make a car game in Unreal Engine. So I am using Vehicle which was used in City sample. At first there was no problem, but after a few days the car suddenly started to behave strangely. Specifically, it started to roll over easily, as if the frictional force of the tires became very high. When I packaged it and played with it in that state, it was normal, but finally it started to roll over easily even when packaged. I have not changed any parameters of the car, so lowering the friction force of the tires does not solve the problem. I don't know what is causing this problem, so please give me a solution.

Change Unreal Engine5 to Unreal Engine4 but it was happen agein.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it rather belongs to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/